# Identify page leading to conversion in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page

GA provides a way to quickly look at traffic sources, campaigns and social networks driving traffic to conversion. I have a email signup form on certain key pages as well as landing pages. Is there a way to look at GA to drill down how many conversions are being driven by these specific pages?

If not is there an easy to implement solution in JavaScript (my site is static) that would allow me to delineate and segment my traffic so I could make such a determination?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to track (e.g., the email signup form on your site or landing pages coming from other sites)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a custom report which can do what I think you want to happen. Try the following link which is a custom report I've setup for this.

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=lZSxJ7XKTH2Z3th4RnTeJw

You will need to 'edit' the report to capture the correct goal id/number as mine will be different to yours.

You will then see the page seen previous to the goal URL, so if it was an email signup you should see a list of pages which lead to the goal being completed.

Comment: I administrate GA over several sites. On one site I get the correct data but on another I get `(entrance)` Do you know what is causing that?